# invalid column name when passing variable mssql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm running into this odd issue with this snippet of code:

```
DECLARE @dbname nvarchar(128)
SET @dbname = $(databaseName)

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE ('[' + name + ']' = @dbname 
OR name = @dbname)))

-- code mine :)
PRINT 'true'
```

I'm passing it through the command line as such:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe" -U user -P password -i C:\checkDB.sql -v databaseName=newdatabasetest1
```

I get this error when I try and run the command here:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server SERVERNAME, Line 2
Invalid column name 'newdatabasetest1'.
```

If I change the query to replace $(databaseName) with 'newdatabasetest1' it works and returns 'true' as expected...

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here or if maybe it's a SQL thing but it seems to only have issue with the command line. I use the same passing variable technique for creating and droping a database which works fine.

Any guidance would be helpful!

Comment: Guessing, but I think you need to quote the string in the SQL script. `SET @dbname = '$(databaseName)'`

Comment: That was exactly the issue! Thank you, never thought about that since it was referenced the other way in all the other scripts

Answer (score 6):

You need to add single quotes to the value assigned to @dbname, like this:

```
DECLARE @dbname nvarchar(128)
SET @dbname = '$(databaseName)'

IF (EXISTS (SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE ('[' + name + ']' = @dbname 
OR name = @dbname)))

PRINT 'true'
```

Comment: #Don,Thank you, I was stacked to the same problem. but when I just add Single quotes to the value assigned, now everything is working perfectly! Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

The Solution to this was to do 
     `SET @dbname = '$(databaseName)'`
instead of
     `SET @dbname = $(databaseName)`
it works in the actual query program, but through the command line it fails, the ticks over the variable fix that